# Configuring a server in IntelliJ for remote work from another IntelliJ instance via SSH

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, server, configuration, remote-access

I have two computers. Let's assume we will call one "**A-client**" and the other "**B-server**". I've been reading various articles and watching YouTube tutorials, but they all show how to connect to an already existing server, i.e., how to configure the client side. I couldn’t find any information on how to configure the “server” side.

What I'd like to achieve is to run JetBrains IntelliJ on computer **B** as an "SSH server". Then on computer **A**, which is the client, I'd like to connect to my computer **B** (the server) and work on a project that's running on computer **B** from computer **A**.

Both computers are running the Windows 10/11 operating system.

Does anyone know how to configure the IntelliJ on computer **B** to act as an SSH server?

Comment: I'm afraid IntelliJ IDEA's Remote Development feature does not support Windows as backend side. The only option in your case would be TeamViewer or something like it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I saw that in Remote Development option in Intellij is information "Windows/Macs will be added in future" or sth like that

Comment: but i had hope , there is maybe some other option to do that ;(